# Error during an object call php soapclient

Tags: php, object, foreach

I'm getting Trying to get property 'timestamp' of non-object while trying to this code:

```
foreach ($BookingA as $object) {

    $Bookings[] = array (
        
        'PID' => $object->person,
        'Project' => $object->levels->WSLevelIdentification->code,
        'Startdate' => $object->from->timestamp,
         'Endddate' => $object->to->timestamp
   
    );

    }
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

When i dump  the data from my array i get the right value

```
array (size=61)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'PID' => string '2036' (length=4)
      'Project' => string '19015' (length=5)
      'Startdate' => string '26.07.2021 12:30:00' (length=19)
      'Endddate' => string '26.07.2021 17:14:00' (length=19)
```

Soap-Output:
The Error is on this Line:  **$object->to->timestamp**

What am I doing wrong?

stdClass Object ( [absence] => [checked] => [complete] => 1 [duration] => 284 [from] => stdClass Object ( [TS] => 1627295400000 [day] => 26 [hour] => 12 [min] => 30 [month] => 7 [sec] => 0 [timeInSeconds] => 1627295400 [timestamp] => 26.07.2021 12:30:00 [year] => 2021 ) [fromBookingID] => 6058 [fullDay] => [levels] => stdClass Object ( [WSLevelIdentification] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 19015 [levelID] => 1 ) ) [notice] => [person] => 2036 [properties] => stdClass Object ( [WSProperty] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 200015 [val] => true/48.2897333/16.3270315/11 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 300015 [val] => true/48.1907349/16.5754274/29 ) ) ) **[to]** => stdClass Object ( [TS] => 1627312440000 [day] => 26 [hour] => 17 [min] => 14 [month] => 7 [sec] => 0 [timeInSeconds] => 1627312440 [timestamp] => 26.07.2021 17:14:00 [year] => 2021 ) [toBookingID] => 6131 )

Comment: _“When i dump the data from my array i get the right value”_ - for _all_ items in the array …? Doubtful. The error message is clear - either `$object->from` or `$object->to` is _not_ an object for at least one of the items you are iterating over.